# Error in nested forms in Rails 5

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I was doing [this](https://jyrkis-blogs.blogspot.in/2014/06/adding-fields-on-fly-with-ruby-on-rails.html) Rails Tutorial on nested forms but whenever I try to submit the form, I get the following error:

> Addresses person must exist

And if I remove the belongs_to :person from the Address model, the code works!

I'm working on Rails 5 and the tutorial is for some previous version but I would really like if it works on Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

try `belongs_to :person, optional: true`